# mongodb aggregating nested values across whole collection with counts

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: 123,
    machine_id: 456,
    data: {
        some_data: 100,
        exceptions: [{
            hash: 789,
            value: 'something',
            stack_trace: 'line 123: oops',
            count: 5,
        }]
    }
}

{
    _id: 234,
    machine_id: 567,
    data: {
        some_other_data: 200,
        exceptions: [{
            hash: 789,
            value: 'something',
            stack_trace: 'line 123: oops',
            count: 1,
        }, {
            hash: 890,
            value: 'something_else',
            stack_trace: 'line 678: ouch',
            count: 3,
        }]
    }
}
```

The hash is a combination of the value and stack_trace (I added this specifically to try to aggregate exceptions across the whole collection).  I want to run a query which returns each distinct exception, along with the total count, and the value and stack trace.  In this case the result would look something like:

```
[{
    hash: 789,
    value: 'something',
    stack_trace: 'line123: oops',
    count: 6,
}, {
    hash: 890,
    value: 'something_else',
    stack_trace: 'line 678: ouch',
    count: 3,
}]
```

I'm quite new to mongoDB, and sturggling to get the aggregation pipeline stages to give me any meaningful output.

Would also welcome comments on structuring this data, if you think there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure looks fine. You can drop the hash if you want and use `value` and `stack_trace` as a grouping key.

You can use below aggregation.

For `$group`ing on `hash`, you will need to `$unwind` `exceptions` embedded array followed by `$first` to keep the `value` and `stack_trace` and `$sum` to count no of distinct exceptions.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$unwind:"$data.exceptions"}, 
{$group:{_id:"$data.exceptions.hash", value:{$first:"$data.exceptions.value"}, stack_trace:{$first:"$data.exceptions.stack_trace"}, count:{$sum:"$data.exceptions.count"}}})
```

Comment: thank you!  it was the initial '$unwind' i was missing!

Comment: seeing as you seem good at this.. can i also ask you quickly the most efficient way to count the total number of all exceptions in the collection?  should I also use an aggregation?  something like:
collection.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$data.exceptions'},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': None,
        'count': {'$sum': '$data.exceptions.count'}
    }},
])

Comment: That seems right or alternatively you can do `db.collection.distinct("data.exceptions.count")` will give you `[5,1,3]` and you can apply sum in your language. For example in JS you can do `sum = [5,1,3].reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);`

Comment: i actually think that doesn't work, because if you have different exceptions with the same count, you will only see one of those counts in your 'distinct' result set.

Comment: Sorry, You are right. I just was too eager to give alternate option without paying attention to what you were asking. So continue using the aggregation option.